# Error Placement for checkbox

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a checkbox in a formwhere I use jquery validation.Here the error message is displayed below the checkbox and the label for the checkbox is displayed after the error.

I need the error message to be displayed after the label for checkbox.
Here is my code:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toc"><span name="toc"> &nbsp;&nbsp;I agree to the terms and conditions
                        </span>
    </input>
</li>
<br>
<li>
    <label style="margin-top:20px;display:none" name="toc" class="error">This field is required</label>
</li>
```

The jquery for the form is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').validate({
        rules: {
            toc: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** put any tag (element) in input tag.